# Convert an array of objects to a dictionary of objects

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

i have an array of events:

```
IEnumerable<CalendarEvent> events
```

i want to convert this to a dictionary so i tried this:

```
   Dictionary<string, CalendarEvent> dict = events.ToDictionary(r => r.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"));
```

the issue is that i have multiple events on a single date so i need a way to convert this to a

```
Dictionary<string, List<CalendarEvent>>
```

to support the days which have multiple events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) instead.

```
var lookup = events.ToLookup(r => r.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"));
```

When you index a lookup, you get an enumerable of all matching results, so in that example `lookup["Sep 04, 2010"]` would give you an `IEnumerable<CalendarEvent>`.  If no results match, you will get an empty enumerable rather than a KeyNotFoundException.

You could also use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) and then ToDictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<CalendarEvent>> dict = events
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"))
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```